# Linux Find command - search by day

Tags: linux

How can I search files modified in a specific day ?

Comment: `man find` -- `find <path> -mtime <n>` where `n` is the number of days to that specific day

Answer (score 2):

Figure out how many days ago that was, and use it without a sign in `-mtime`.

Answer (score 2):

```
 touch --date "2010-11-01" /tmp/foo(some temp file which is not important)
 touch --date "2010-11-02" /tmp/foo2(some temp file which is not important)
 find /some_folder -newer /tmp/foo ! -newer /tmp/foo2
```

This gives you the files in some_folder which are modified newer than or the same date to  "2010-11-01" and not newer than "2010-11-02".

Comment: You forgot to create a second file with a date a day later and invert the search on it.

Comment: I've fixed it and added a newer date boundary.